# django migration like model reference

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have a model like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = "Foo"
    super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now whenever I create or update any Book type instance it's name will be set to "Foo". That's fine. This is exactly what I want!

Meanwhile in django migrations if I use `migrations.RunPython` I get special django apps instance and this is how stuff works in migrations file:

```
Book = apps.get_model('my_app.Book')
book = Book()
book.name = 'Young Life'
book.save() 
print book.name
>> 'Young Life'
```

My custom save method was ignored.

Question - How can I get my models to behave the same way as they do in migrations? Or how can I ignore my custom built save methods when using my instances not in django migrations?

Comment: It explains why it's not working https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/migrations/#historical-models

Comment: I know why it's not working in migrations. My question is how to achieve the same behavior outside of migrations if I need that for some reason?

Comment: It's best to use the pre_save/post_save signals with your Book model, as the save method on a model doesn't always get called -- e.g. when using `Book.objects.update(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured this out my self.

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.db.migrations.state import ProjectState

naked_apps = ProjectState.from_apps(apps).apps
Book = naked_apps.get_model('my_app.Book')

book = Book()
book.name = 'Young Life'
book.save() 
print book.name
>> 'Young Life'
```

Comment: You are getting into Django internals and this code is liable to break in future versions. I suggest you add a special version of save() that just calls super().save() without doing any processing and use it when you do not want custom behavior.

Comment: Agree, but adding special save version is not an option as then I would have to alter 20+ models on different applications and even on some third party ones... later maintain all of that complexity...